# Create Dynamic List within a Wiki Page

Tags: list-view, wiki

I am attempting to find a way to create a dynamic list with a wiki. The list should only show the entries related to the current wiki page based on a column the list entry and the wiki page have in common called Position ID. However, the entire list needs to be an aggregate for all the wiki pages to be visible in a different view. Is there a way to do this?

[image]